# Autoscroll Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automate a scroll of 750px once the user has scroll 1px
 , but reached 750 that I would scroll back to normal and the effect start again only if I am at the top of the page .

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function ($){
   $(window).scroll(function (event) {
     var body = $("html, body");
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     body.stop().animate({scrollTop:750}, '1500');  
   });
});
```

This is my code , but continues to scroll automatically to 750px how can I stop the event and start it again only if im ot the top of the body ?

Comment: Resolve with this : jQuery.noConflict()(function ($) {

 var isAtTop = true;

 $(window).scroll(function (event) {

  var body = $("html, body");
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if ( isAtTop ) {
   body.stop().animate({scrollTop:750}, '1500');
   isAtTop = false;
  } else {
   if ( scroll == 0 ) {
    isAtTop = true;
   }
  }

 });

});

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add an if around the animate call.

```
if(scroll == 0){
    body.stop().animate({scrollTop:750}, '1500');
}
```

otherwise everytime you scroll it will call the animate  and return to 750px position

Comment: But `scroll == 0` condition wouldn't be reached the first time you scroll down

Comment: Mh, thx for reply but this doens't work,  because now every time i try to go up on my site jquery scroll down.. so i need to go on menu but i cant

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, you want the scroll event to be fired only when the top of page has been reached. So you could toggle a class on the `body` element:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var $body = $('body');
  if ($body.hasClass('onTop')) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 750
    }, '1500');
  }
  $body.toggleClass('onTop', scroll === 0);
}).scroll(); // trigger it on load or set it directly in HTML markup: <body class="onTop">
```